# H-space multiplication question (homotopy)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $(X,x_0)$ be a $H$-space with multiplication $\mu:X\times X\to X$.

Let $e$ denote the constant map $I^n\to x_0$.

Is it true (and why) that
$\begin{cases}
\mu(f(2x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),e),&x_1\in[0,1/2]\\
\mu(e,g(2x_1-1,x_2,\dots,x_n)),&x_1\in[1/2,1]
\end{cases}$

is homotopic to $\mu(f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),g(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))$?

I am not sure how the multiplication $\mu$ in $H$-spaces work, other than that it is continuous.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an Eckmann-Hilton argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true if $f|_{x_1=1}$ and $g|_{x_1=0}$ are constant maps to $x_0$, otherwise the maps that you define will be not continuous.

Let $f_t(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n):=
\begin{cases}
f((2-t)x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),&x_1\in[0,(1+t)/2]\\
x_0,&x_1\in[(1+t)/2,1]
\end{cases}$

and $g_t(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n):=
\begin{cases}
x_0,&x_1\in[0,(1-t)/2]\\
g((2-t)x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),&x_1\in[(1-t)/2,1]
\end{cases}$

Then the product $\mu(f_t(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),g_t(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))$ will be a desired homotopy.